# Strange PHP charset issue?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-8

I got a strange problem in a webapplication of mine.

It's an application that stores data about metal products, and thus uses the Ø-symbol a lot.
When I run the application on my Windows 7 or my Vista pc (both 32-bit), the Ø is stored as Ø.
When I run the application on my Windows 8 (64-bit) the Ø is stored as oslash; which I do not want.

I use on all systems the same version of the application, Apache, MySQL and PHP. Configuration files (httpd.conf and php.ini) are as good as the same (except the paths).

Also when I connect with my Windows 8 with the application running on the windows 7 of Vista, everything works fine and Ø is stored as Ø.
The other way around, using vista to run the application on windows 8, then i get oslash;

My html pages contain :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
```

PHP pages start with :

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
```

DB access :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
```

and I use the following to get the value from HTML in PHP :

```
htmlentities($_POST[$name]);
```

But this can't really be the problem because it works on win7/Vista

Anyone got an idea what can be the problem and how I can fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: mysql has nothing to do with this. it will **NEVER** do entity encoding for you. that's not its job. If you get oslash out of mysql, that's because you stuffed oslash into mysql in the first place.

Comment: You should use `htmlentities` only in combination with `echo`. Do not use it on values you insert into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask for the html entity, the right behavior is to obtain `oslash;`. The faulty installation is the old one where this character is not detected as having to be entity decoded.

Now, as explained by @GhostGambler in the comment, the real problem is that **you do not need to request the html entity decoded version of the input** before inserting it in the database.

If you do that for a *security* reason then you're doing it *wrong*. The rule is to **filter/escape everything depending on the destination.**

- When you store something on a database, all the things you use should be filtered against the SQL language abuse.
- When you output something on an HTML page, your dynamic user content should be escaped against HTML
- same rule for other destinations, like json, csv, etc

`htmlentites` is an html escaper, it prevent any strange character like '<' to be interpreted as a a real character part of the HTML syntax. And it also convert characters with special encodings to an html entity (like `oslash;`) to avoid encoding problems. And on this second task, where security is less important, the list of converted characters may be altered from one version of PHP to another.
You can test this list of converted characters with the function [`get_html_translation_table`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php):

```
var_dump(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'WINDOWS-1252'));
var_dump(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
(..)
```

As a side note, htmlentities is also a function which could be used with character encoding parameters, if you know what is the encoding of the data loaded from the database:

```
htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

You will certainly need a call to this htmlentities function, but it should be set just before the HTML output, maybe on a completly different part of the code, on the `view` part.

To secure your input before using it in the database you have other solutions:

- using `mysql_real_escape_string`
- using parametized queries (by far the best)
- (...)